Did Haru Manipulate Tokaku into Protecting Her?
In episode 11, Haru and Tokaku go talk with the Chairman. She (the Chairman) claims that, because Haru is a Queen Bee, she can manipulate Tokaku into protecting her so she can survive the 11 attempts to kill her(and even her classmates?). Haru denies that, claiming that she would never do such a thing to a friend or anyone at all. So, is the Chairman right about Haru manipulating Tokaku, or is Haru right about not manipulating Tokaku or her classmates? 

I think that Haru did not manipulate Tokaku because Tokaku was able to "Kill" Haru in the end, even though Haru did not die because of her titanium ribs.
